# Updating javascript Array of objects returns duplicates in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I'm writing a chat app in a vue project and tinkering around with it.

Full featured one needs to be able to live-update "seen" states, so as one user sees the last sent message, the other gets a previously grey dot next to his sent message to change to the other persons profile pic in small (not that important to the problem).

I'm using socket.io that triggers stuff all around back and forth as this happens.

The flow works great so far, except the following part:

```
 messagesArray.value.findLast(function (message: any) {
        if (message.showUnRead === true && message.senderID === data.senderID) {
          delete message.showUnRead;
          message.read = true;
        }
        if (message.showRead === true && message.senderID === data.senderID) {
          delete message.showRead;
          message.read = true;
         
        }
```

So when I first wrote this, worked great, except that when I added the object value changes parts, it duplicated back itself to the array.

> It did not only update the `messagesArray.value` 's last object, it updated and put back it twice (or in other words, it updated the last one, then put another replica of it, after it).

This only happens when I add the object function (the 'delete message.showRead' or 'message.read' functions).

I'm guessing that the `findLast()` function returns the object itself again and adds this returned object back into the array, and thats why this happens.

I do not want to use any `array.pop()` function, since that messes with the animations, since I have a `transitiongroup` animation whenever a new message arrives (or in other words, when the array gets a new object or when an existing one gets deleted). Also it seems redundant, changing object's values gets the objects, changes value, then returns object back then I need to delete the duplicated one, but I might be wrong.

What I want to achieve is that it simply changes the found (`findLast()`) object's certain key-values.

So my question is

1. is there a function that does this?
2. if there isn't, how should I approach this without getting the pop() induced animation chaos not to appear?

I have tried the pop(), slice(), splice() methods, all creating more chaos then needed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To be able to answer your question, we need a concise, self-contained code snippet with which we can play. As it stands, it's hard to see from your description where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: I would write the logic like this, once you find how to do it `if (message.senderID === data.senderID) {  if (message.showUnRead || message.showRead) message.read = true; if (message.showUnRead) delete message.showUnRead; if (message.showRead) delete message.showRead;  }`

Comment: the duplication only happens the moment the code runs the 'message.read = true' or any similar changes to the "selected" (either by findLast() or any other that I've tried function) object.

Comment: Dear @gog ! The whole code is reliant on socket.io back and forth triggers, it would probably take a few hours for someone who isnt working on it to understand. Basically, in 1 logical stream of processes, I just upload the message with senderID and sendToID a date and a 'read = false' to a server, on the other logical stream, I'm live-tinkering with the objects through socket.io in order to display 'seen' and 'unseen' states. When a user sends a message, I made it so it sends it to his own array of messages too, works great, renders correctly.

Comment: @gog then I send this through socket.io if and only if, the other user is present in the chatting panel. Then that user recieves the message, puts it in his array, and if that new message is inView in the chatpanel, sends back to the original sender a trigger. This trigger makes the previously sent message, that had "unseen" as default state, to change to "seen" state. That requires this piece of code that I copypasted. No matter how I select in the original sender's array the last object (it will always be the sent message), as soon as I update the object, it duplicates itself into the array.

Comment: First of all: No the code you show here, surely doesn't remove or add in the array it is called upon. If you see such effects it must be something you do later on with this array. Second, modifying an array element in `find` (or any of its derivates) is rather uncommon. Typically the callback of `find` (or any of its derivates) just checks some condition on the element it curretly looks at and returns either `true` or `false`. Once the callback returns `true` for an element, `find` then returns this element. And again, it does not add or remove elements in the unerlying array.

Comment: So to be able to help you, please post some more code which allows us to *reproduce* this behaviour. I don't say, the array isn't modified, I don't even deny, these modifications started to happen once you introduced this code. But still, this code doesn't add or remove elements in an array. But some other part of the code may, based on the modifications of the elements you apply here ...

Comment: @derpirscher I appreciate very much the answers, and you were right. There was another full on "Answer" to my question, but the guy since deleted it, in it I wrote it might be something else triggering the object to be pushed, and you (and initially me) were right.
Case is the following: its a vue project, and I had multiple modules/views for this chat panel. The *send message* button along with it the function of what to send (input), was on a diff module, then the one that shows and deals with the array of messages.

Comment: @derpirscher So in one module, I press the send button, and on another, I need to show that sent message.
To achieve this, I was using simply the *props* functionality of vue: I "prop" into this "messages renderer module", whatever the input is in the sending module.
Then in the "messages renderer module", I am "watching" this props.message with vue's watch method. When its changed (and it changes every time you send one, so far so good), it pushes the new message into the array so it renders.

Comment: Problem is, I was simply using within this *watch* method the new message, and just pushed THAT into the array. Instead what I need to do, is create a copy by using **{...newMessageValue}**

Comment: I simply pushed the newMessageValue into the array, so therefore, whenever it changed (and I did in order to add and remove "seen" and "unseen"), it triggered itself, and pushed itself back again once more.

Comment: I will later on write a comprehensive explanation with the 2 modules ("parent" module that has the send button, and "child" module that recieves it with the props), so that its easy to see what happened and why. In order for you to catch this, I would have needed to copy about 200 lines of code and still you wouldnt be able to see it, cause its a project in which im rendering parts based on signed in info, socket.io connected or not states etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would like to address, that ***the actual problem with my code was NOT with the findLast() function or my usage with it***.

But since this kind of logical oversee of debugging happens quite a lot, I myself have seen incorrect answers regarding my (initially wrongly identified) problem too,

> *it may help people to remind themselves that sometimes you don't
> find the solution, because you incorrectly thought that you identified
> the problem itself correctly, just haven't found the solution*.

I am building a chat app, that has the functionality to show with a rendering of either a grey circle or a small circle with the other users prof pic the "unseen" and "seen" states, and the system uses mongodb as offserver message-database, and socket.io for a "live-server".

I have a "parent" module, in which you can input the text and send it to the other user, and a "child" module in which all the messages are structured to the left or right side of its container, corresponding to if you sent the message or you recieved it from the other user.

This "child" module's messages are in an array, which gets downloaded from a server at its first render, and if and only if the other user is also present in the chatwindow (he/she also opened the same chatpanel corresponding to their chat), this array gets updated on both sides using socket.io triggers back and forth.

The messages themselves are objects, containing the message as string, date, senderID and sendToID, and a "read" key with a default value of "false".

The original problem occured, when I was back and forth triggered the following process through socket.io:

1. sender user sends message (also updates the mongodb database with a
   default value for "read" of "false") --> also, **sender user's child component gets updated through props with the newly sent message, gets its own messagesArray updated with the message by using watch functionality of vue**

> The child component recieving the message

```
    watch(
      () => props.selfMessage,
      (newvalue) => {
      
        messagesArray.value.push(newvalue);
      },
      { deep: true }
    );
```

2. reciever recieves the message through socket.io, his/her array gets updated with the message
3. reciever's script checks (with vueUse's vElementVisibility function) if the
   new message has "read" as "false" (which it does at first recieve),
   and then if the vElementVisibility is triggered (it was in view),
   changes its state of "read" to "true", AND, sends back through
   socket.io a "readMessage" trigger
4. original sender gets this "readMessage"  trigger, and updates its own messagesArray's last message (which is always the last send message) by changing "read" to "true" --> rendering of grey cirle to profile-pic-circle happens

During process number 4, this was the code mentioned in the original question:

```
    props.socket!.on("messageRead", function (data: any) {
       messagesArray.value.findLast(function (message: any) {
    if (message.showUnRead === true && message.senderID === data.senderID) {
      delete message.showUnRead;
      message.read = true;
    }
    if (message.showRead === true && message.senderID === data.senderID) {
      delete message.showRead;
      message.read = true;
     
    }

    });
```

> ***During this last process, this "messageRead" trigger is running a function, that changes the lastly added message object === which was
> originally, pushed into the messagesArray by simply adding the
> selfMessage 's newvalue from the parent module, INTO the array***

That actually means, and *this is what I didn't know and had to learn* by trying out if this might be the problem, is that
***I should have NOT pushed the newvalue from selfMessage into the messagesArray, since that is, in itself, if changed, triggers the watch function of vue to run again, which contained the messagesArray.value.push(newvalue) to trigger again***

What I need to do with the props.selfMessage and watch, is ***creating a copy of this newvalue, and insert that into the messagesArray***

```
    watch(
      () => props.selfMessage,
      (newvalue) => {
       
        const newMessage = { ...newvalue };
        messagesArray.value.push(newMessage);
      },
      { deep: true }
    );
```

Moral of the story, if you have a quite complex process, always check back to the roots of what and where does the process start from, it might be something you overlooked, and wasn't a problem before, but a new functionality along with the original not-so-good-method, creates one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please rewrite the bot so that it doesn't flag comprehensive and extensively explained, thorough answers as "unclear"